# Animating vertical Menu with jQuery is not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate

Basically, I have a `<nav>` element that should be expanded from left to right on `mouseover`, but sometimes if you quickly put the pointer over and then out of the element, it will work without animation and that shouldn't be happening.

Here is the HTML code:

```js
$('#navigation').hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    left: 190
  }, {
    duration: 500
  });
}, function() {
  $(this).animate({
    left: 0
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    queue: false
  });
});
```

```css
nav.menu-nav {
  margin-left: -190px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #edf0f3;
  border-right: 1px solid #f7f8fa;
}

.menu-nav h1 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}

.menu-nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-nav li {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  position: static;
  margin: 20px 0 -20px -50px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  transition: 1s background-color;
}

.menu-nav li:hover {
  background-color: #a5b3c3;
}

.menu-nav a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

button.account {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
}
.acc-register {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.acc-login {
  margin-left: 105px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylsheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<nav class="menu-nav" id="navigation">
  <h1>
    mipagina
  </h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <button class="account acc-register btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Register
  </button>
  <button class="account acc-login btn btn-default">
    <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login
  </button>
</nav>

<div class="contenido">
  <p>
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
    sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
    incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate
    velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
  </p>
</div>
```

If you have any clues on what I am doing wrong here to let this happen (or you have any suggestion on what should I change) let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. Have you tried adding a `.stop()` before `.animate()` to make sure animations don't get queued in unwanted ways? I find it solves most animate-queue-related problems (which this sounds like, but not 100% sure)

Comment: @blgt, it works great with .stop() before .animate(). Post it as an answer and I will mark it as the correct one. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can use `.stop()` before `.animate()` to clear the animation queue before starting a new animation:

```
$('#navigation').hover(function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({
    left: 190
  }, {
    duration: 500
  });
}, function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({
    left: 0
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    queue: false
  });
});
```

This gives more fine-grained control over animation timing. I find it solves most animate-queue-related problems

ref. https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS instead of jQuery for this:

```
nav.menu-nav {
  margin-left: -190px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #edf0f3;
  border-right: 1px solid #f7f8fa;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
}
nav.menu-nav:hover{
  -ms-transform: translateX(190px); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translateX(190px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: translateX(190px) ;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xopbnuot/1/)

Edited to make transition out twice as long as transition in.

Comment: Note that the animation time differs when it's expanded and when it's not.

Comment: That should make it so it takes 0.5s to transition in and 1s to transition out, like in your js. JSFiddle is updated too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with event "hover". For solving the problem I can propose you close your menu only after 0.3sec.

Example:

```
// Close dropdown list after 0.3sec
    var timeoutId;
    jQuery("#menu").hover(function() {      
        if (timeoutId) {
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = null;
      }
      else {
        jQuery(this).addClass('opened');
      }
    }, function () {            
      if (!timeoutId) {
        timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
          timeoutId = null;
          jQuery("#menu").removeClass('opened');
        }, 300);
      }
    });
```